# How to properly initialize Vuex store on app startup using rest API?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nativescript, vuex, nativescript-vue

I want to initialize the store with some data that is fetched from API (I'm using axios) How can I do this on app startup, only once?

I have a store.js file that exports my store and a main.js file that does this:

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import store from "./store";

new Vue({
  store,
  render: (h) => h("frame", [h(App)]),
}).$start();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `.dispatch()` with your Axios REST API grabbing function in the `created()` hook in the main Vue component (the one you included store in):

```js
new Vue({
  store,
  render: (h) => h("frame", [h(App)]),
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('myAxiosFetchFunction');
  },
}).$start();
```

Comment: created hook on which component? I want it to be run only once for the whole app.

Comment: In the main component, in the component where you put `new Vuex.Store(store)`.

Comment: Well, I don't know the component layout of your app, but the master/parent component sounds like the right choice, since you're probably gonna have only one copy of it...

Comment: @Ali that is not a component. That is store.js file... oooh you mean the main.js file in the Vue instance

Comment: @Zaroth can you update your answer based on my edit?

Comment: I just did. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Zaroth why not store instead of this.$store?

Comment: `this.$store` is a standard way to referring to vuex store object once it has been included in the root component - see [vuex documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html)